# Different SRID problem

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arccatalog, srid

I have two geodatabases and I import a large number of tables from one to another by using ArcCatalog (ArcGIS 10.2). However the tables and indexes created on them are imported with different srid.  Lets say, for the same table in geodatabase-1 srid that I am using is 6 but in geodatabase-2 it is 30002. I need to set srid for all tables to 6. The reason why I need same srid's is that two geodatabases must act like clones to each other.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you need the SRID to be identical?  The value is fed by a sequence, and is supposed to be different by database.  The fact that you have a 1 sequence and a 30001 sequence indicates you have different versions of ArcGIS involved as well (please edit the question to contain these versions, and the database in use).

Comment: Now posted on [geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/message/478848) as well.